# Выводить попап Try again при нажатии на страницу, кроме некоторых элементов (bind, closet, e.target)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вся задумка в том, чтобы пользователь шел за "сценарием" и нажимал только на определенные блоки, а при нажатии на не тот выскакивал попап Try again. 
**Исключения:** 
`$('.tabs li')` - название табов (вверху скрина) 
`$('.can-click')` - блоки, по которых можно нажимать (рандомно на всех табах) 
`$('.table')` - таблица ячеек 
**Допольнительно:** 
`$('.try-again')` - сам попап Try again

**Задача:** 
Все вроде как работает: когда нажимаю на блоки-исключения то ничего не происходит, но когда я первый раз разму мимо так же ничего (на сколько я понимаю это из-за того что `$(document).bind('click.body', function(e)` только применился и еще не успел сработать. Но потом когда я хочу обратно нажать на исключение, то показывает Try again. Я понимаю в чем проблема, но не могу профиксить - нету опыта.

[image: Скрин табов и таблицы]

```js
$(document).bind('click.exclusion', function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).closest($('.tabs li')).length != 0 && $(e.target).closest($('.can-click')).length != 0) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        } else {
            $(document).bind('click.body', function(e) {
                if ($(e.target).closest($('.table')).length == 0) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    $('.try-again').show();
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $('.try-again').hide()
                    },1000);
                } else {
                    $(document).unbind('click.body');
                    $(document).bind('click.myEvent', function(e) {
                        if ($(e.target).closest($('.find')).length == 0) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            $('.try-again').show();
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                $('.try-again').hide()
                            },1000);
                        } else {
                            $($('.find')).show();
                            $(document).unbind('click.myEvent');
                            $(document).bind('click.myEventReplace', function(e) {
                                if ($(e.target).closest($('#find-replace')).length == 0) {
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    $('.try-again').show();
                                    setTimeout(function(){
                                        $('.try-again').hide()
                                    },1000);
                                } else {
                                    $($('#find-replace')).show();
                                    $(document).unbind('click.myEventReplace');
                                    $(document).bind('click.myEventReplaceWhat', function(e) {
                                        if ($(e.target).closest($('#replace-what')).length == 0) {
                                            e.preventDefault();
                                            $('.try-again').show();
                                            setTimeout(function(){
                                                $('.try-again').hide()
                                            },1000);
                                        } else {
                                            $($('#find-replace')).show();
                                            $(document).unbind('click.myEventReplaceWhat');
                                            $(document).bind('click.myReplaceAll', function(e) {
                                                if ($(e.target).closest($('.replace-all')).length == 0) {
                                                    e.preventDefault();
                                                    $('.try-again').show();
                                                    setTimeout(function(){
                                                        $('.try-again').hide()
                                                    },1000);
                                                } else {
                                                    if ($('#replace-what').val() === 'n/a' || $('#replace-what').val() === 'N/A') {
                                                        $(document).unbind('click.myReplaceAll');
                                                        var numberEnd = window.storage.endCell.slice(9,window.storage.endCell.length);
                                                        var numberStart = window.storage.startCell.slice(1,window.storage.startCell.length);
                                                        var endFor = Number(numberEnd)+1;
                                                        for (var i = numberStart; i < endFor; i++) {
                                                            if ($('#sheet1__'+window.storage.startCell.slice(0,1)+i).text() == $('#find-what').val()) {
                                                                $('#sheet1__'+window.storage.startCell.slice(0,1)+i).html('<div>'+$('#replace-what').val()+'</div>');
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        $('.done').show();
                                                        setTimeout(function(){
                                                            $('.done').hide()
                                                        },2000);
                                                    } else {
                                                        $('.try-again').show();
                                                        setTimeout(function(){
                                                            $('.try-again').hide()
                                                        },1000);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Посмотри тут](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {
  alert('try again');
});
$('.can-click, .tabs li, .table').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs">
  <li>tab1</li>
  <li>tab2</li>
</ul>
<div class="can-click">can-click</div>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>.table</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: у меня выводиться попап, а не алерт

Comment: Не суть...это пример того, что событие не распространяется на указанные селекторы. Вместо алерта вставь $('.try-again').show();

Comment: спасибо. не пришлось возиться с bind'ами. как всегда ответ в одну строку)))